# Given: $\sum n a_n$ is convergent. To prove: The sequence ${a_n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given: $\sum n a_n$ is convergent. To prove: The sequence ${a_n}$ converges.

My proof:

Since $\sum n a_n$ is convergent, so $na_n \rightarrow 0,$
i.e., $\frac{a_n}{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow 0. $

As the denominator of tends to $0$, so the limit $\frac{a_n}{\frac{1}{n}}$ would exist only if the numerator ${a_n}$ tends to $0$, so that an indeterminate form is formed. Thus ${a_n}$ is convergent.

Is it okay? I am not satisfied with it.

It seems to me that the proof lacks some explanation.

I think the argument

"As the denominator of tends to $0$, so the limit $\frac{a_n}{\frac{1}{n}}$ would exist only if the numerator tends to $0$"

requires some more explanation.

Comment: Simpler: write $a_n = \frac{1}{n}\cdot (na_n)$. Both factors converge to $0$, so ...

Comment: Except we don't have that first inequality. What are you trying to show, @Imago? We are given $na_n\to 0$.

Comment: By the way, are you sure you weren't asked to show $\sum a_n$ is convergent? @ParveenChhikara

Comment: ah, nvm - my thoughts were not structured and in fact similar to Parveen Chhikara's approach.

Answer (score 5):

For $n\neq 0$, $0\leq |a_n|\leq |na_n|$. Use the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).